# Can't import PIL after installing Pillow with Poetry

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-poetry

I'm trying to install and use Pillow with Python 3.9.2 (managed with pyenv). I'm using Poetry to manage my virtual environments and dependencies, so I ran `poetry add pillow`, which successfully added `Pillow = "^8.2.0"` to my pyproject.toml. Per the Pillow docs, I added `from PIL import Image` in my script, but when I try to run it, I get:

```
File "<long/path/to/file.py>", line 3, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

When I look in the venv Poetry is creating for me, I can see a PIL directory (`/long/path/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/`) and an Image.py file inside it.

What am I missing here? I've tried:

- Downcasing to `from pil import Image` per [this](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3851#issuecomment-568223993); did not work
- Downgrading to lower versions of Python and PIL; works, but defeats the purpose
- ETA: Exporting a requirements.txt file from Poetry, creating a virtualenv with venv, and installing the packages manually; works, but cuts me off from using Poetry/pyproject.toml

Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: How do you run your script? Did you activate the venv before?

Comment: What is the output of the command `poetry run python <your script.py>`?

Comment: @finswimmer: My process was:

1. `poetry shell` to activate the venv; 

2. `poetry install`: technically unnecessary, because `add` should install things, but good to confirm. Output was: `No dependencies to install or update`; 

3. `python script.py`; this is where I get the output `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'`

Comment: @ont.rif: Huh. That seems to work correctly (well, it hops to an error with tkinter, but I think I know how to work around that).

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way to solve this either (using poetry 1.1.13).

Ultimately, I resorted to a workaround of `poetry add pillow && pip install pillow` so I could move on with my life. :P

`poetry add pillow` gets the dependency in to the TOML, so consumers of the package *should* be OK.

Answer (score 1):

capitalizing "Pillow" solved it for me:

`poetry add Pillow`